# I need to pull unique patients that meet certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I pulled `person_nbrs` that have never had an EventType1 before or after an EventType2. I need to pull person_nbrs that have not had an EventType1 prior to having an EventType2.  If they had an EventType1 after an EventType2, than it is to be ignored.  Here is my query that pulls person_nbrs that have never had an EventType1 before or after EventType2.

```
SELECT 
    person_nbr, enc_nbr, enc_timestamp 
FROM 
    person p
JOIN  
    patient_encounter pe ON p.person_id = pe.person_id  
JOIN 
    patient_procedure pp ON pe.enc_id = pp.enc_id 
WHERE
    enc_timestamp >= '20170101'
    --EventType2
    AND code_id LIKE '2'    
    --  EventType1
    AND person_nbr NOT IN (SELECT person_nbr
                           FROM person p
                           JOIN patient_encounter pe ON p.person_id = pe.person_id  
                           JOIN patient_procedure pp ON pe.enc_id = pp.enc_id
                           WHERE code_id LIKE '1') 
GROUP BY 
    person_nbr, enc_nbr, enc_timestamp 
ORDER BY 
    person_nbr ;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Also, what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.person_nbr
FROM person p JOIN
     patient_encounter pe
     ON p.person_id = pe.person_id JOIN
     patient_procedure pp
     ON pe.enc_id = pp.enc_id
GROUP BY p.person_nbr
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN pp.code_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND -- has code 2
       (MAX(CASE WHEN pp.code_id = 1 THEN pe.timestamp END) IS NULL OR
        MAX(CASE WHEN pp.code_id = 1 THEN pe.timestamp END) < MIN(CASE WHEN pp.code_id = 2 THEN pe.timestamp END)  
       ) ;
```

The `HAVING` clause has two parts:

- The first specifies that the person has a code = 2.
- The second specifies one of two conditions.  The first is that there is no code = 1.  The second alternative is that the latest c = 1 timestamp is less than the earliest code = 2 timestamp.